# How to change spacing in array (block matrices)

Tags: matrices, arrays, vertical-spacing, strut

[image: Block matrix]

I want to add a certain spacing s.t. the the partial derivative symbols don't touch the line. Here is the code I have so far.

```latex
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{D}_{}F(\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0}) = 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
        \textbf{I} 
  & 0 \\
\hline
        \displaystyle  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{x}} (\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0}) &
       \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{y}} (\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0})
  \end{array}\right]
.\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `\\[-2ex]` after `\hline`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{D}_{}F(\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0}) = 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
        \textbf{I} 
  & 0 \\
\hline\\[-2ex]%<--
        \displaystyle  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{x}} (\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0}) & 
        \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{y}} (\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0})\\
  \end{array}\right]
.\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the easiest answer!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest that you insert a (typographic) strut in a superscript position next to one of the two `\partial f` expressions.

I would also replace all nine instances of `\textbf` with `\mathbf`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\dfrac' macro
% Define a "tall" typographic strut with no width:
\newcommand\mystrut{{}^{\mathstrut}\kern-\scriptspace} 
\begin{document} 
\[
\mathrm{D}_{}F(\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0}) = 
\left[\begin{array}{@{} c|c @{}}
  \mathbf{I} & 
  0 \\
  \hline
  \dfrac{\partial f\mystrut}{\partial\mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0}) &
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{y}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0})
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A superscript, even if empty, adds a `\scriptspace`; admittedly, it's `0.5pt`, so I can see it only at 1600% magnification on my screen, but there might be situations where this leads to unexpected behaviour. But +1 anyway...

Comment: @campa - Thanks for this observation. I'll happily append `\kern-\scriptspace` to the definition of `\mystrut`. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, from now on I will use `\mathbf` as you recommended!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `cellspace`, with adds a minimal vertical spacing at the top & bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` by default. I took the liberty to remove the `align*` environment, since nothing is aligned in this formula, and to replace `\textbf` with the more appropriate ``\mathbf`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

  \[ \mathrm{D}_{}F(\textbf{x}_{0}, \textbf{y}_{0}) =
\left[\begin{array}{>{$ \displaystyle}Sc<{$}|>{$ \displaystyle}Sc<{$}}
        \textbf{I}
  & 0 \\
\hline
        \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0}) &
       \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{y}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0})
  \end{array}\right]
  \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You need to define a command to add padding below and above its argument as follows

`\newcommand{\addstackgapmath}[2][\Sstackgap]{\addstackgap[#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}}`

Fot matrices containing horizontal and vertical lines, it is good practice to use `bNiceArray`

Off-Topic: it is better to enter bold math using `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\addstackgapmath}[2][\Sstackgap]{\addstackgap[#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{D}_{}F(\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0}) = 
    \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
        \mathbf{I} 
        & 0 \\
        \hline
        \addstackgapmath{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0})} &
        \addstackgapmath{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{y}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0})}
    \end{array}\right]
.\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{D}_{}F(\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0}) =
    \begin{bNiceArray}[hvlines-except-borders,margin]{c c}
        \mathbf{I} 
        & 0 \\
        \addstackgapmath{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0})} &
        \addstackgapmath{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{y}} (\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{y}_{0})}
    \end{bNiceArray}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```